# "The token request must specify a 'grant_type" when sending a token request with value with Got

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, appdynamics, node.js-got

I am using JavaScript for API programming to monitor URL's health check.
This is for API monitoring in AppDynamics.
Need to use GOT library.

I am checking response of the HTTP request.

```
const assert = require("assert");

(async() => {
  var url = "https://example.com/oauth2/v1/token";
  var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic xyz'
  };
  var payload = {
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'scope': 'okta.groups.read okta.users.read',
    'username': 'userid',
    'password': 'xxxxx'
  };
  var response = await client.post(url, {
    headers: headers,
    json: payload,
  })
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(response.statusMessage);
  console.log(response.body);

})();
```

But I see below response.

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The token request must specify a 'grant_type'. Valid values: [password, authorization_code]"}

I did clearly mention `'grant_type': 'password'` in the code with payload variable.
I admit, I am new to JavaScript, but I looked at lot of online examples, but still could not figure out, why got library does not recognize payload.

Comment: Your `payload` is not valid JSON. Try it with proper double-quotes.

Comment: Or use `json: JSON.stringify(payload)` it'll take care of it.

Comment: @Marc `payload` is not even a string, much less valid or invalid JSON. It's a plain JS object. Changing how the properties of an object are quoted won't change anything `{ foo: 42 }` and `{ 'foo': 42 }` and `{ "foo": 42 }` and `{ ["foo"]: 42 }` are *exactly* equivalent when it comes to producing an object with a property `foo`. Quoting, not quoting, or even evaluating an expression make no difference.

Comment: Bit of a wild guess but should maybe the `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` header be `'Content-Type': 'application/json'` instead? Either that, or if you stick to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then should probably send your body as URL encoded data but JSON is probably just easier to handle in general.

Comment: @Lauromine I tried with json: JSON.stringify(payload), still got same error

Comment: @VLAZ I tried with body: JSON.stringify(payload)  with 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. I see same error.

Comment: That's neither of the two things I suggested, though.